# Programmatically removing "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" in Excel

Tags: .net, excel, powershell

In PowerShell, I'm attempting to change the format of cells in Excel 2013 from **General** to **Number** but the format is not applying due to the cell value being a **number stored as text**.

If I were using Excel normally and saw the green triangles, I could just *select all* and convert all cells with the error to a number in a single click. I hope there is some programmatic way to do this.

One solution I have seen proposed is to copy the cell's value back to itself after changing the formatting:

```
    $cell.NumberFormat = "0"
    $cell.Value() = $c.Value()
```

but this works incredibly slow when applied to an entire UsedRange. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: How about copying the entire `UsedRange` and then using `PasteSpecial(-4163)` to paste the whole thing back as just values?

Comment: Clever idea, but I tried it and it didn't work. The numbers were still stored as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a really fast way. What we're going to do is find the first blank row past your `UsedRange`, and get the first cell in the row. Then we set that cell to a numeric value of 1, and copy that cell. Then we use the `PasteSpecial` method, and have it perform the Multiply operation on the UsedRange. This will convert everything to a number. Then we delete the row that we populated during this process, and you're all set.

```
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$XL.Workbooks.Open($File)
$BlankCell = $XL.ActiveSheet.Rows.Item(($($XL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows)[-1].Row+1)).Cells.Item(1)
$BlankCell.Value2 = 1
$BlankCell.Copy()
$XL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(-4163,4)
$BlankCell.EntireRow.Delete()
```

[XlPasteType Enumeration Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) for the -4163 reference, and [XlPasteSpecialOperation Enumeration Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838010.aspx) for the 4 reference in the PasteSpecial operation.